# Difference in releasing the CGColorSpaceRef by calling CFRelease versus using CGColorSpaceRelease?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, memory-management, core-graphics

Suppose I'm using `CGColorSpaceRef`. I'm wondering if there is a difference between releasing the `CGColorSpaceRef` by calling `CFRelease` versus using `CGColorSpaceRelease`?

i.e., a difference between this:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

// do stuff

CFRelease(colorspace);
```

versus doing:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

// do stuff

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [CGColorSpace Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGColorSpace/Reference/reference.html):

> This function is equivalent to CFRelease, except that it does not cause an error if the cs parameter is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Either is acceptable. The second one will check for `NULL` however, so it lets you skip a line of code. You must *always* check for `NULL` before calling `CFRelease()`. If you don't and `NULL` is passed in, it will crash.